# how to make content appear on another div when title is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css

i'm new to javascript and i'm trying to create a page where the entry titles will be on the left (the sidebar) and when clicked, the content will appear on the right (main). the problem is that the content is appearing directly below the title, not by its side.
i tried changing the content to the div it's supposed to be in and when i click the title nothing even happens. any ideas on how to fix this?

```js
var entries = document.querySelectorAll(".entry");
for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
  var el = entries[i];
  el.addEventListener("click", function () {
    var itemId = i;
    var allEntries = document.querySelectorAll(".entry");
    if (this.nextElementSibling.className.match("show")) {
      this.nextElementSibling.classList.remove("show");
    } else {
      this.nextElementSibling.classList.add("show");
    }
    for (var j = 0; j < allEntries.length; j++) {
      if (this == allEntries[j]) {
        continue;
      }
      allEntries[j].nextElementSibling.classList.remove("show");
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.entry {
  color: #d49a95;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px;
}

.entry-content {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="sidenav">
    <div class="entry">test</div>
    <div class="entry">test2</div>
  </div>
  <main>
    <center>
      <p class="entry-content">helloo</p>
      <p class="entry-content">hiiii</p>
    </center>
  </main>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you're using `nextElementSibling()` from the clicked `.entry` elements, yet they have no sibling. From the description of the issue it looks like you're trying to access the related `.entry-content` elements, however they are children of a sibling to the parent of the `.entry`.

To simplify the issue you could relate them by index within their respective parent elements, like this:

```js
const entries = document.querySelectorAll(".entry");
const contents = document.querySelectorAll('.entry-content');

const getChildIndex = el => [].indexOf.call(el.parentNode.children, el);
const hideAllContent = () => contents.forEach(c => c.classList.remove('show'));

entries.forEach(entry => {
  entry.addEventListener('click', e => {
    hideAllContent();
    
    const index = getChildIndex(e.target);
    contents[index].classList.add('show');
  });
});
```

```css
.entry {
  color: #d49a95;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px;
}

.entry-content {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="sidenav">
    <div class="entry">test</div>
    <div class="entry">test2</div>
  </div>
  <main>
    <center>
      <p class="entry-content">helloo</p>
      <p class="entry-content">hiiii</p>
    </center>
  </main>
</div>
```

Or alternatively you could use `data` attributes on the `.entry` elements to directly specify which `.entry-content` should be displayed:

```js
const entries = document.querySelectorAll(".entry");
const contents = document.querySelectorAll('.entry-content');
const hideAllContent = () => contents.forEach(c => c.classList.remove('show'));

entries.forEach(entry => {
  entry.addEventListener('click', e => {
    hideAllContent();
    document.querySelector(e.target.dataset.content).classList.add('show');
  });
});
```

```css
.entry {
  color: #d49a95;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px;
}

.entry-content {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="sidenav">
    <div class="entry" data-content="#content-a">test</div>
    <div class="entry" data-content="#content-b">test2</div>
  </div>
  <main>
    <center>
      <p class="entry-content" id="content-a">helloo</p>
      <p class="entry-content" id="content-b">hiiii</p>
    </center>
  </main>
</div>
```

Also, as an aside, using things like `cursor: pointer` to make a non-clickable element behave like a clickable element is ***very*** bad practice. I would strongly suggest you change the `.entry` elements to `<a />`, calling `preventDefault()` if you don't want the links to actually go anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:
Since I've changed the JavaScript entirely, I added the `onclick="showWindow(n)"` attribute to the `.entry` navigation buttons. And on the `.entry-content` divs, I've added `data-window:n` attributes. Now the good thing about this is, you can add as many nav items and content windows as you want. What you have to do is just

- Make a navigation button (`.entry`) and add the `showWindow(n)` attribute as well but replace n with a number, e.g. 4 since it has not been used before.
- Make a content window (`.entry-content`), and give it the `data-window:"n"` attribute, where `n` is same as the `n` in the navigation button, so 4 in this case.

Now when you click the navigation button with the `showWindow(4)` attribute, it'll show the content window with `data-window="4"` attribute. Also added a close button.

CSS: 
Declared styles for the close button. Used flex-box on `.main` to display content window next to the navigation bar. `flex: 2;` property on main so it takes up all the available space.

Javascript: 
So I've made a lot of changes here. Honestly, a completely different approach to get the desired result. The code you attached, returns errors when ran. Hence, I've rewritten the entire JavaScript code.

- Cross Event-listener 
  On clicking the cross button, `.active` class is removed from all elements.
- showWindow(n) Function 
  When called, The element with `data-attribute=n` is stored in the `window` variable. Then a loop runs which removes `.active` class from all content windows.
  `.active` class is then added to `.cross` and the window stored in `window` variable.

```js
let entries = document.querySelectorAll(".entry");
let windows = document.querySelectorAll("[data-window]");
let cross = document.querySelector(".close");

cross.addEventListener("click", () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < windows.length; i++) {
    windows[i].classList.remove("active");
  }
  cross.classList.remove("active");
});

function showWindow(n) {
  let window = document.querySelector(`[data-window="${n}"]`);
  for (let i = 0; i < windows.length; i++) {
    windows[i].classList.remove("active");
  }
  cross.classList.add("active");
  window.classList.add("active");
}
```

```css
body,
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
}

.sidenav {
  padding: 0 10px;
}

main {
  position: relative;
  flex: 2;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.entry {
  color: #d49a95;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 15px;
}

.entry-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0 10px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.entry-content.active {
  visibility: visible;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}

.close {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  --size: 18px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.close.active {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.close.active:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.close:before,
.close:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: var(--size);
  width: 2px;
  background-color: #333;
}

.close:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.close:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="sidenav">
      <div class="entry" onclick="showWindow(1)">Window 1</div>
      <div class="entry" onclick="showWindow(2)">Window 2</div>
      <div class="entry" onclick="showWindow(3)">Window 3</div>
    </div>
    <main class="container">
      <p class="entry-content" data-window="1">Content 1</p>
      <p class="entry-content" data-window="2">Content 2</p>
      <p class="entry-content" data-window="3">Content 3</p>
      <i class="close"></i>
    </main>
  </div>
</body>
```